# MongoDB aggregate to extract values from a nested array and return a total

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have this collection structure:

```js
[
   "_id": "61a013b59f9dd0ebfd23ftgb",
   "modules": [
     {
       "_id": "61a013b59f9dd0ebfd964dgh",
       "videos": [
         {
           "_id": "213412",
           "progress": 100
         },
         {
           "_id": "61a013b59f9dd0ebfd965f4a",
           "progress": 0
         },
       ]
     },
     {
       "_id": "43556hujferwdhgsdft",
       "videos": [
         {
           "_id": "fdsg3sg98er989890",
           "progress": 66
         },
         {
           "_id": "fdsg3sg98er989890",
           "progress": 100
         },
         {
           "_id": "fdsg3sg98er989890",
           "progress": 100
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 ]
```

I am trying to return the overall progress for each "module" by adding up all the videos that have progress of 100 and creating a percentage based on number of videos in the module.  For example, the first module should return **"module_progess"** of 50 within it as this has 1/2 videos completed.

```js
{
   "_id": "61a013b59f9dd0ebfd964dgh",
   "module_progress": 50,
   "videos": [
     {
       "_id": "213412",
       "progress": 100
     },
     {
       "_id": "61a013b59f9dd0ebfd965f4a",
       "progress": 0
     },
   ]
},
```

How do i access each videos object to make this calculation and add the new field to the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- map on modules
- and add a field on each with the avg progress of the videos

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70226677)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"modules": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$modules",
        "in": 
        {"$mergeObjects": 
          ["$$this",
           {"module_progress": 
             {"$avg": 
               {"$map": 
                 {"input": "$$this.videos.progress",
                  "in": 
                  {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$progress", 100]}, "$$progress", 0]},
                  "as": "progress"}}}}]}}}}}])
```

Query2

- unwind
- replace root to make structure better
- add the avg field

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70226677-1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": {"path": "$modules"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$modules"}},
  {"$set": 
    {"module_progress": 
      {"$avg": 
        {"$map": 
          {"input": "$videos.progress",
            "in": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$$this", 100]}, "$$this", 0]}}}}}}])
```

Comment: this is awesome - and close.  Rather than an average, however, if a video is not 100% completed it needs to be classed as 0.  So, the second module for example would be 2/3 complete, so 66.6%.  How would I do this?

Comment: i updated it, with one extra map before avg, you could also do a reduce and sum divide, but this works also, just query got a bit bigger

Comment: Amazing.  Learnt a lot from this.  Thanks.